# javascript select first non falsey value shows error with array index

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the syntax of:

```
someVar = otherVar || ''; 
// set someVar to otherVar, or '' if otherVar is false
```

when I turn otherVar into some array key,

```
someVar = otherVar[1] || ''; // otherVar[1] is undefined.
```

i get the error

> Cannot read property '1' of undefined

This makes sense since otherVar[1] is undefined...But -

**Question**: Is the only way to prevent this, to check if `otherVar[1]` is truthy before setting `someVar`? Or can I still use this easy method to do set variables quickly like an if else?

I also tried

```
someVar = (!!otherVar[1]) ? otherVar[1] : ''; // didn't work either.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first test that `otherVar` exists so you cannot really do it with that syntax, but you could do this:

```
someVar = otherVar && otherVar[1] ? otherVar[1] : '';
```

This works because the and statement fails before the test for the index.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Why would checking for the key instead of the whole array not work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is your case where the variable *is* declared but `undefined`. You can use this little trick, cryptic but neat:

```
var arr; // declared but 'undefined'
var result = (arr || [,'foo'])[1];

console.log(result); //=> "foo"

arr = [1, 2]; // declared and defined
result = (arr || [,'foo'])[1];

console.log(result); //=> 2
```